# Stick it together

Tags: grammar

I bought shoes with straps for him.

We were going to watch a film.

He put his foot in the shoe but didn't stuck the straps together.

> "Stick it together."

I said.

What is the action to stick the straps?

Does it clearly saying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be safe with any of these:

> 1. "[Do up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/do-up) your straps."
> 2. "Do up your shoes."
> 3. "[Fasten](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fasten) your straps."

If the strap is a buckle, you could also

> 4. "[Buckle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buckle) your straps."
> 5. "Buckle up your shoes."

Comment: Can I say "Fasten your shoes" for shoes with straps?

Comment: I wouldn't personally (which is why I didn't include it), but searching for the term reveals that at least [some people say that](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-do-you-fasten-your-shoes.65441/).